# wamp server and production acting differently

Tags: php, apache, wamp

My webpage allows the user to drag-and-drop upload an input file, some manipulation and conversion takes place, and then an output file is saved to a publicly accessible location on the Web server.  Lastly, a link to the generated file is provided to the user.

The code below (abbreviated) works just fine on my WAMP server but when I upload the code to a production host, it no longer works.    The WAMP Apache version is 2.4.9 and the WAMP PHP version is 5.5.12.  Production server is Apache version 2.2 and PHP version 5.3.27.  I realize the versions aren't the same - is it possible that is the issue?  I'd rather not mess with the versions of the production server, but I would if needed.

I have checked the Windows permissions of the folder my script attempts to write to and as part of trouble shooting have opened them to full control for everyone.  (this is actually an internal webserver, so I'm not super concerned)

EDIT/UPDATE: Based on @Itay Moav -Malimovka suggestion, I'm included firebug output.  I'm new to firebug, so I'm not entirely sure the best way to display results (there is obviously a ton of data).

The dragover and drop events appear to go fine. As do the fileSetup event, sent and inputSetup events (though digging deeper, there is lots of buried red and 'undefined' values).  Then, the POST event has a 500 internal server error in filehandler.php.

- *Response Headers*
- **Connection** close
- **Content-Length** 0
- **Content-Type** text/html
- **Date** Sun, 02 Nov 2014 03:05:06 GMT
- **Server** Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.27
- *Request Headers*
- **Accept** text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
- **Accept-Encoding** gzip, deflate
- **Accept-Language** en-US,en;q=0.5
- **Content-Lengt**h 34124
- **Content-Type** application/octet-stream
- **Host** domain.com
- **Referer** http://domain.com/path/index.html
- **User-Agent** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
- **X-File-Date** Tue, 23 Sep 2014 22:10:03 GMT
- **X-File-Name** smallInputFile.rdb
- **X-File-Size** 34124
- **X-Requested-Wit**h FileDrop-XHR-FileAPI

I'm unsure what else to check.  What would you check next?  I believe it has something to do with server setup rather than the code (due to the fact it works on a default WAMP server) but for completeness, I'm including (abbreviated) relevant code is below:

(index.html)  -- note that the alerts don't even fire when on the production server.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/ddup/filedrop.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset id="zone">
        <legend>Drop a file inside&hellip;</legend>
        <p>Or click here to <em>Browse</em>..</p>
    </fieldset>
    <span id="status"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var zone = new FileDrop('zone', options);    
        // Do something when a user chooses or drops a file:
        zone.event('send', function (files) {
        // Depending on browser support files (FileList) might contain multiple items.
        files.each(function (file) {
            // React on successful AJAX upload:
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            zone.el.appendChild(p);
            file.event('done', function (xhr) {
                // 'this' here points to fd.File instance that has triggered the event.
                alert('Done uploading ' + this.name);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
                alert('Done uploading ' + this.name + ', response:\n\n' + xhr.responseText);
        });

            file.event('progress', function (sent, total) {
                p.textContent = 'Uploaded ' + Math.round(sent / total * 100) + '%...';
            })

          // Send the file:
          file.sendTo('fileHandler.php');
        });
      });
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(fileHandler.php)

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// If an error causes output to be generated before headers are sent - catch it.
ob_start();

/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');

if (!empty($_FILES['fd-file']) and is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name'])) {
  // Regular multipart/form-data upload.
  $filename = $_FILES['fd-file']['name'];
  $filedata = file_get_contents($_FILES['fd-file']['tmp_name']);
} else {
  // Raw POST data.
  $filename = urldecode(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']);
  $filecontents = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $filedata = explode("\n",$filecontents);
}

//**** do stuff to file ****//


// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$fileBase = explode(".",$filename);
$outFilename = $fileBase[0] . date('His') . ".xlsx";
$url = "xlsxFiles/$outFilename";
$objWriter->save($url);
echo "<br><table class=\"rulesTable\" id=\"linkRow\"><tr><td><span id=\"finalLink\">Link to generated XLS file: <a href=\"$url\">$outFilename</a></span></td></tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: Can u fire up your firebug and see what goes in the Console tab?

Comment: Will try firebug (I've been using Chrome tools) and report back. Fred, I tried removing the semi-colon to no effect...

Answer (score 1):

Is your production server running a `*NIX OS`?

If it is, this line may well cause it to complain

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');
```

In *NIX the path seperator is a colon `:` and not a semi colon `;`

There is a Predefined constant called `PATH_SEPERATOR` that allows you to be OS agnostic so try this instead

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../Classes/');
```

Comment: The production server is running windows 2012.  Still, good info about PATH_SEPARATOR.  Thanks.